# Index limit for access array with pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, math, integer

I pass a pointer to a big array defined in Python (millions of rows) to a C-function with ctypes.

In the C-part I do pointer arithmetic on this array to access the values of it. Now I get some weird/false calculations and I think it's because of the pointer arithmetic.

As I understand pointers are always integers so the last entry of the array I can access would be the maximum integer value of that specific system.

So what does happen if I try to access `*(array+i)` where i is bigger than the maximum integer? And if that's the case how can I access remaining entrys of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern operating systems use a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model), which means that a pointer is able to represent any address in the virtual address space.

On 64-bit systems, pointers are 64 bits, on 32-bit systems, they are 32 bits.

On 32-bit operating systems, the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of every process is 2^32 bytes, which is several billion bytes (i.e. several gigabytes).

On 64-bit operating systems, the virtual address space of every process is 2^64 bytes, which is an astronomically high number.

> So what does happen if I try to access *(array+i) where i is bigger than the maximum [pointer]?

You will never encounter such a situation on systems with a flat memory model, since a pointer is always large enough to represent any address in a process' virtual address space.

It may be theoretically possible for you to encounter such a situation on a system with a [segmented memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation). However, that is certainly not the reason why you are having the problem you describe.

> As I understand pointers are always integers so the last entry of the array I can access would be the maximum integer value of that specific system.

The last element of the array that you can legally access depends on how much memory you allocated for the array.